# Is it possible to enforce calendar event time periods?

Tags: 2013, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I need to limit the start and end times for calendar events. Basically the events need to occur within a single day. Is this possible?

For example this would be permitted: 
12/2/2014 4pm - 12/2/2014 7pm

But this would be blocked: 
12/2/2014 4pm - 12/3/2014 7pm

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at List Settings -> Validation Settings. You can put a Excel-look-a-like formula there. You can put something in like

```
=DAY([BeginDate]) = DAY([EndDate])
```

(untested). It will only accept items where the DAY values of both date fields are equal.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me: =DAY(Created)=DAY([End Time])